# What does software engineer(laterals) means?

Tags: consultants

I was about to apply to position in company careers page. But they have mentioned `software engineer(laterals)`. I don't have an idea about this. What does this mean?

Comment: my understanding is that it covers a wide range of skills rather than just coding. But I'm not really sure so just commenting.

Comment: Laterals?  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lateral

Comment: [Lateral Computing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lateral_computing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means whatever the company chooses it to mean. The correct answer is **ask them**. Asking them is not a sign of weakness on your part, it shows your personal interest in that position, which is a good thing. If they do take note, it will be positive.

When going by the normal meaning of the word lateral, it may mean that they accept people from other fields. Where I live, lateral (or rather it's translation, "Seiteneinstieg") means you get in from the side. Not from below the position (which would be a more junior position or school), not from above (demoted supervisor) and not from the same position, but from a different job.

For example in times where teachers for CS were needed, they'd accept laterals: People that weren't educated teachers, but normal developers willing to learn on the job what it takes to be a teacher.

For a software developer that could mean they are taking people from QA or IT or maybe math teachers that hate their former job. Anyone that seems to fit but doesn't necessarily have a degree in CS.